# Oracle Case statement with Name and empID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables one table contains a role type of the engineer and the second table is the emp table.

My column Primary_eng and secondary_ENG contains EMP_ID, I need the name instead of the EMP_ID.

MY Employee table contains the name as FIRST NAME and LAST NAME. I also want to pass a Parameter with ENG Name.

My condition:

```
CASE WHEN (PRIMARY_ENG = :P_DBA AND secondary_ENG != :P_DBA) THEN 1 
            WHEN (PRIMARY_ENG != :P_DBA AND secondary_ENG = :P_DBA) THEN 2 
            ELSE 3 END
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Provide insert, create table scripts and exact output expected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have created a view with subqueries and call out the name with the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
As other user's have pointed out, please consider posting more details such as:

- structure of your tables
- sample data
- expected output

Assuming the following based on the limited info you've provided:
1. You have an `employee` table with `emp_id`, `first_name` and `last_name`

```
|EMP_ID |FIRST_NAME |LAST_NAME  |
|100    |John       |Smith      |
|200    |Peter      |Scott      |
|300    |Priyank    |Bhasin     |
```

2. You have a set of roles ( let's say a table `role_types` ) with each role having a primary engineer's emp_id ( `primary_eng` ) and secondary engineer's emp_id ( `secondary_eng` )

```
|ROLE_TYPE  |PRIMARY_ENG    |SECONDARY_ENG  |
|DBA        |100            |200            |
|DEV        |200            |300            |
|TESTER     |300            |100            |
```

3. By passing an `emp_id` you need:
 (a) the employee's full name 
(b) a custom parameter which is a priority based list of roles to which the employee is assigned

Solution:

- You can fetch the engineer's name by joining both tables concatenating first_name and last_name
- The parameter you've defined can also be fetched using a direct join of both tables

```
select r.role_type,
e.first_name||' '||e.last_name as engineer_name,
CASE WHEN (PRIMARY_ENG = 100 AND secondary_ENG != 100) THEN 1 
            WHEN (PRIMARY_ENG != 100 AND secondary_ENG = 100) THEN 2 
            ELSE 3 END as my_param
from role_types r
  join employee e on r.primary_eng = e.emp_id
  order by 3
;
```

Output:

```
|ROLE_TYPE  |ENGINEER_NAME  |MY_PARAM   |
|DBA        |John Smith     |1          |
|TESTER     |Priyank Bhasin |2          |
|DEV        |Peter Scott    |3          |
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2090/7)

If this doesn't work, please enhance your question with additional details
If this suits your requirement, feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/65088#65088) and [vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments/173400#173400)